# Paramiko get sorted directory listing

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am able to get a directory listing from Paramiko.  And with `listdir_attr` I get the attributes.  However, I need to sort this list by filename.  If it returned a list of dictionaries I could use lambda to do the sort.  But with it returning a list of `SFTPAttributes` I can't figure out how to do the sort other than creating a new list of dictionaries containing the data I care about and sorting that list.  Before doing that is there a way to get a directory listing that is sorted by filename?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way to make [`SFTPClient.listdir_attr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr) return a sorted list.

Sorting is easy though:

```
files = sftp.listdir_attr()
files.sort(key = lambda f: f.filename)
```

Or for example, if you want to sort only files by size from the largest to the smallest:

```
from stat import S_ISDIR, S_ISREG
```

```
files = [f for f in files if not S_ISDIR(f.st_mode)]
files.sort(key = lambda f: f.st_size, reverse = True)
```