# Order SFTP files by date

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am connecting to an SFTP folder with a list of files. I need to order these by date and extract the latest two.

```
filepath= "/test/sftp/files/"
localpath= "C:/myfiles/"

os.get(filepath, localpath)
```

I can extract all the files by using the `os.get` but I tried `os.listdir` but this does not order by date which I need. I looked in the `os` library but can't find something to order by date.

I'm using Paramiko.

Comment: See also [Paramiko get sorted directory listing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53822548/850848).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to `listdir` which only give the name of the remote files, paramiko provides a `listdir_attr` method which return a list of `SFTPAttributes` containing the filename and also a `st_mtime` field (among others). You have just to sort that list on that `st_mtime` field to get the list of files ordered by their (modification) date:

```
client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
client.connect(...)                       # use your connection parameters here
sftp = client.open_sftp()
remote_files = [x.filename for x in sorted(sftp.listdir_attr(), key = lambda f: f.st_mtime)]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
class MyClass1
      {
          public string DataTime { get; set; }
          public string DataTimeUTC { get; set; }
          public string Path { get; set; }  
    }
  
  SftpClient client = new SftpClient(con);
                  client.Connect();
                  var files = client.ListDirectory("");

    foreach (var file in files)
                 {
  newData.AddRange(new List<MyClass1>() {
  new MyClass1() { Path =  file.Name, DataTime = $"{file.LastWriteTime}", DataTimeUTC =  $"{file.LastWriteTimeUtc.Ticks}" } });
  }

  newData.Sort((a, b) => a.DataTimeUTC.CompareTo(b.DataTimeUTC));
```

Comment: This does not look like Python.