# How to sort file list pulled from SFTP server using Paramiko by modification date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

I have this code that pulls files from a server using Paramiko. How can I get these files sorted by modification date?

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
# automatically add keys without requiring human intervention
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )

ssh.connect(sftpURL, username=sftpUser, password=sftpPass)

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
filesInSFTP = sftp.listdir(sftpPullDirectory)
# Get only the XML and XLSX files
filesInSFTP = [file for file in filesInSFTP if file.lower().endswith(('.xml', '.xlsx'))]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Retrieve the listing with file attributes (including the modification time) using [`SFTPClient.listdir_attr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr). And then sort the list by [`SFTPAttributes.st_mtime` field](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_attr.SFTPAttributes).

```
filesInSFTP = sftp.listdir_attr(sftpPullDirectory)
filesInSFTP.sort(key = lambda f: f.st_mtime)
```

---

Related questions:

- [How to get the latest folder that contains a specific file of interest in Linux and download that file using Paramiko in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60218092/850848)
- [Paramiko get sorted directory listing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53822548/850848)

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.